# Best PostgreSQL datatype for storing key-value maps?

Tags: json, postgresql, sqldatatypes, jsonb, hstore

I'd like to store a simple map of key-value strings as a field in my PostgreSQL table. I intend to treat the map as a whole; i.e, always select the entire map, and never query by its keys nor values.

I've read articles comparing between `hstore`, `json` and `jsonb`, but those didn't help me choose which data-type is most fitting for my requirements, which are:

- Only key-value, no need for nesting.
- Only strings, no other types nor `null`.
- Storage efficiency, given my intended use for the field.
- Fast parsing of the queried maps.

What data-type would best fit my use case?

Comment: Definitely `hstore`

Comment: IIRC, `jsonb` is implemented as a nested `hstore`, so that should work, too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'd live it if you'd elaborate on that :)

Answer (score 5):

you could use hstore which is a keymap, however I personally would us jsonb. It's a little overkill, however, most languages can convert json natively without having to decode it yourself.

In json, I'd just store a simple object or array for the info you're trying to store.

Both support indexes and are efficiently stored.

Hstore in text is a custom type format that your language may be unaware of and thus require processing the data to insert or query.

Comment: Depending on the programming language `hstore` does not need any "conversion". The JDBC driver for example simply returns a `Map` for the contents of a `hstore` column