# How to add a map field to the database?

Tags: spring, postgresql

I'm trying to create a table with such fields, but I can't figure out how to add a field(name and url) with the type map in postgresql

```
public class RequestToPlanfix {
private String cmd;
private String providerId;
private String channel;
private String chatId;
private String planfix_token;
private String message;
private String title;
private String contactId;
private String contactName;
private String contactLastName;
private String contactIco;
private String contactEmail;
private String contactPhone;
private String contactData;
@Convert(converter = Attachments.class)
private Map<String,String> name;
@Convert(converter = Attachments.class)
private Map<String,String> url;
private Boolean isEcho;


CREATE TABLE "requestToPlanfix" (
id     SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY ,
cmd    TEXT NOT NULL,
providerId TEXT NOT NULL,
channel TEXT NOT NULL,
chatId TEXT NOT NULL,
planfix_token TEXT NOT NULL,
message TEXT NOT NULL,
title TEXT NOT NULL,
contactId TEXT NOT NULL,
contactName TEXT NOT NULL,
contactLastName TEXT NOT NULL,
contactIco TEXT NOT NULL,
contactEmail TEXT NOT NULL,
contactPhone TEXT NOT NULL,
contactData TEXT NOT NULL,
name
url
```

)

that is, I don’t know how to write type fields to name, url which are maps, such as for example cmd text not null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best PostgreSQL datatype for storing key-value maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261128/best-postgresql-datatype-for-storing-key-value-maps)